# How to connect modal form to mysql database?

Tags: html

I connected my database and my modal form (register form), I tried to input some 3 profile data, but they only appears 2 profile data at database. Tried to re input the last profile data but nothing happens.

When I enter the email `andreas@gmail.com`, it doesn't work but when I enter `andreas1@gmail.com`, it appears in the database. Why?

I tried to create a new form and drop the database.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal2">Register</button>
```

I want all my profile data to go to my database. Here is the full code https://www.onlinenotepad.pro/wmhbr?view

Answer (score 0):

the answer of the email question is because in the database cannot have same input. so you can Encrypt that email OR Check the email at database. example

```
enter code here
// get the data from modal
$email = $_POST['example_email'];

// get email from database 
// the example you already get from database and put into variable $user_email

then you can check it :)
if ( $email == $user_email) {
// redirect to the register page that you already make
header("Location: SignUp.php");
echo "The user already in database, try to use another email :)";
```